# Test breaks when using Future.delayed

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: Fade in FAB]

I have used a `Future.delayed` to show a FAB in 1 second using this code:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  setState(() {
    _showFab = true;
  });
});
```

Now the most basic smoke test has stopped working:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

This is the error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.
'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 933 pos 7:
'_currentFakeAsync.nonPeriodicTimerCount == 0'    import 'dart:async';
```

Here is all the code used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showFab = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        _showFab = true;
      });
    });

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _showFab ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1400),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I change the unit test to make the test pass?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to give the tester enough time to process all the async calls you have scheduled, try change your smoke test to something like this:

```
void main() {
    testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    // Since you wait 1 second to start the animation and another 1.4 to complete it
    await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 3));

    expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

You will also need to move the `Future.delayed` out of the `build()` method, because this is causing a cyclic behaviour, every time you call `setState()` the `build()` is called again, change your state like that:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showFab = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        _showFab = true;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _showFab ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1400),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I'm still getting the same error with this smoke test. Even with `await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 2));` it still has the same error message.

Comment: You're waiting 1 second to start the animation that takes 14000ms, so it is 2400ms.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that still leads to the same strange error. I tried `await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 4))` just to be safe as well as `await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 3))` but still get the same error.

Comment: ohh I see now, you're adding the fab on your 'onBuild' method, that is causing a cyclic behaviour, move the call to init state.

Comment: Thanks, the onBuild was the issue as well

Comment: If I am using tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1)); on place of  tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 2 or 3 or 4 or what so ever)) it still working

Answer (score 37):

The test framework runs with `FakeAsync` by default, that has some limitations and might cause the error you get.

You can explicitly run with async proper like:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

      expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

You might still need suggestions made in other answers.

Comment: This answer also works when combined with the answer from @Panthro . Thanks

Comment: Yeah, normally you shouldn't need that. I run into a situation with rxdart where tests only worked with `test.runAsync`.

Comment: This solved it for me when I used `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => { ... })` to resolve a Provider service in the widget's `initState` method.

Comment: this solution starts to fail in Flutter 2.5.1 with the following test exception:
`'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 1254 pos 12: '_currentFakeAsync !=
null': is not true.`, they seem to rely on `FakeAsync` as the only option here.

Comment: Should be answer #1

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your Widget with [TickerMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TickerMode/TickerMode.html).

As you can see below:

```dart
void main() {
    testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(TickerMode(child: MyApp(), enabled: false));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me for the same error `A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.`

Answer (score 5):

Try calling [pumpAndSettle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) after you've pumped the widget. Like this:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

From the docs

> This essentially waits for all animations to have completed.

Comment: Just tried that, I still have the same error message

Comment: oh ok, you might have to pass in a duration to your pumpWidget method call. `await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp(), Duration(seconds: 1));`

Comment: This also didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `pump` and `pumpAndSettle` but it didn't work. But add `Duration` in `pumpAndSettle` (not work for `pump`) makes it work again

```dart
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
```