# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe) flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, provider

this is my splash screen and I provide the future method to navigate automatically to another screen,

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<DataBaseProvider>(context).getAllEmployees();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListViewEmployees()));
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListViewEmployees()));
            },
            child: Text(
              'Hello!' ,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.deepPurple ,
                fontSize: 18 ,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error message

```
E/flutter ( 8699): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 8699): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 8699): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter ( 8699): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3825:9)
E/flutter ( 8699): #1      _Closure.call (dart:core-patch/function.dart)
E/flutter ( 8699): #2      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3839:6)
E/flutter ( 8699): #3      Element.findAncestorStateOfType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3958:12)
E/flutter ( 8699): #4      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2185:40)
E/flutter ( 8699): #5      SplashScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:gsg_sqlitedb/ui/splash_screen.dart:12:17)
E/flutter ( 8699): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 8699): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 8699): #8      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
E/flutter ( 8699): #9      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 8699): #10     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
E/flutter ( 8699): #11     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:519:7)
E/flutter ( 8699): #12     new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:322:16)
E/flutter ( 8699): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 8699): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 8699): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 8699): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 8699): #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 8699): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 8699): #19     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter ( 8699): #20     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter ( 8699): #21     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter ( 8699): #22     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter ( 8699): #23     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

when I delete future delayed, and make the navigate by a button click, the error disappear

**SOLVED !!!!!! here**
[Test breaks when using Future.delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021267/test-breaks-when-using-future-delayed)

Comment: Solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021267/test-breaks-when-using-future-delayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test breaks when using Future.delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021267/test-breaks-when-using-future-delayed)

Comment: @WasAsh You should add the answer as a reply to the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that you're trying to Navigate to a page while the current screen is still being rendered. `Future.delayed()` can be potentially used as it provides a delay while the current screen is being built. What happens when the screen being built is still not finished and `Future.delayed()` is that the workaround causes issues.

Another workaround is setting a fixed Timer

```dart
Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
  // Navigate to next screen
});
```

It's still best to avoid automatically navigating to a next screen if possible.